# Python не читает данные файла Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Пишу код `python` для чтения данных файла `Excel` используя функцию `read_excel()` модуля `pandas`.
Вот код `dav4.py` :

```
import pandas


excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('task4.xlsx', sheet_name='Data', usecols=['market', 'mode'])

print(excel_data_df)
```

Но выдается следующая ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\dav4.py", line 6, in <module>
    excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel(
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 364, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1191, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1070, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 711, in get_handle    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'task4.xlsx'
```

Объясните как решить эту проблему.`Python` и `Excel` файлы находятся в одной папке , но все равно ошибка

Comment: как минимум попробуйте указать полный путь до файла

Comment: @finally без указания полного пути никак по другому это не решить?

Comment: А где, относительно файла скрипта, реально находится файл который Вы пытаетесь открыть?

Comment: У вас неправильный заголовок. Не "питоне не читает файлы эксель", а "питоне не находит файл". Умение точно и правильно определить проблему - хороший навык для поиска решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую воспользоваться [этим решением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/5741205):

```
import inspect
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

def get_script_dir(follow_symlinks=True):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): # py2exe, PyInstaller, cx_Freeze
        path = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
    else:
        path = inspect.getabsfile(get_script_dir)
    if follow_symlinks:
        path = os.path.realpath(path)
    return os.path.dirname(path)

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(get_script_dir(), 'task4.xlsx'), sheet_name='Data', usecols=['market', 'mode'])
```